# Complex row and column Manipulations pandas

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas, time-series

I am trying to perform both row and column operations at same time. I have a data with time series. I did check almost all the examples here and in document but no much luck and have been more confused than before.

I have two files both in same path

```
Path = '/'

File_1.csv 

Nos,00:00:00,12:00:00
123,5245,624
125,4534,65
567,642,7522


File_2.csv
Nos,00:00:00
123,20
123,20
123,20
125,50
125,50
567,500
567,500
567,500
567,500
567,500
```

The expected output is merging the `col[last]` count of `file_1.csv` to `file_2.csv` as new column while performing the following operations:

1. Take the value of `Nos=123` it occurs `3` times in `file_2.csv` so divide the corresponding value i.e. `624/3 = 208`.
2. Now put this new value by adding the value of `00:00:00` from same row corresponding to `Nos` in new column that will have header of `col[last]` from `file_1.csv`. i.e. `208+20=228`

Now the appended `file_2.csv` looks like:

```
File_2.csv
    Nos,00:00:00,12:00:00
    123,20,228
    123,20,228
    123,20,228
    125,50,82/83 #float to be rounded off
    125,50,82/83
    567,500,2004 #float rounded off
    567,500,2004
    567,500,2004
    567,500,2004
    567,500,2004
```

This looks super complex to understand from where to start with. Any suggestions to move forward towards writing a code would be huge help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the two dataframes into one:

```
In [34]: df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1[['Nos', '12:00:00']], on=['Nos'], how='left')

In [35]: df3
Out[35]: 
   Nos  00:00:00  12:00:00
0  123        20       624
1  123        20       624
2  123        20       624
3  125        50        65
4  125        50        65
5  567       500      7522
6  567       500      7522
7  567       500      7522
8  567       500      7522
9  567       500      7522
```

then you can perform a `groupby/transform` to count how many items are in each group:

```
count = df3.groupby(['Nos'])['12:00:00'].transform('count')
```

The value you wish to compute can then be expressed as

```
df3['12:00:00'] = df3['00:00:00'] + df3['12:00:00']/count
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('File_1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('File_2.csv')

last1, last2 = df1.columns[-1], df2.columns[-1]
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1[['Nos', last1]], on=['Nos'], how='left')

count = df3.groupby(['Nos'])[last1].transform('count')
df3[last1] = df3[last2] + df3[last1]/count 
print(df3)
```

yields

```
   Nos  00:00:00  12:00:00
0  123        20     228.0
1  123        20     228.0
2  123        20     228.0
3  125        50      82.5
4  125        50      82.5
5  567       500    2004.4
6  567       500    2004.4
7  567       500    2004.4
8  567       500    2004.4
9  567       500    2004.4
```

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
df3[last1] = df3.groupby(['Nos']).apply(lambda x: x[last2] + x[last1]/len(x) ).values
```

instead of

```
count = df3.groupby(['Nos'])[last1].transform('count')
df3[last1] = df3[last2] + df3[last1]/count
```

However, it is slower since the `groupby/apply` is doing an addition and division once for each group, whereas

```
df3[last1] = df3[last2] + df3[last1]/count
```

is performing the addition and division on whole columns. If there are a lot of groups the difference in performance can be significant.Merge the two dataframes into one:

```
In [34]: df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1[['Nos', '12:00:00']], on=['Nos'], how='left')

In [35]: df3
Out[35]: 
   Nos  00:00:00  12:00:00
0  123        20       624
1  123        20       624
2  123        20       624
3  125        50        65
4  125        50        65
5  567       500      7522
6  567       500      7522
7  567       500      7522
8  567       500      7522
9  567       500      7522
```

then you can perform a `groupby/transform` to count how many items are in each group:

```
count = df3.groupby(['Nos'])['12:00:00'].transform('count')
```

The value you wish to compute can then be expressed as

```
df3['12:00:00'] = df3['00:00:00'] + df3['12:00:00']/count
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('File_1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('File_2.csv')

last1, last2 = df1.columns[-1], df2.columns[-1]
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1[['Nos', last1]], on=['Nos'], how='left')

count = df3.groupby(['Nos'])[last1].transform('count')
df3[last1] = df3[last2] + df3[last1]/count 
print(df3)
```

yields

```
   Nos  00:00:00  12:00:00
0  123        20     228.0
1  123        20     228.0
2  123        20     228.0
3  125        50      82.5
4  125        50      82.5
5  567       500    2004.4
6  567       500    2004.4
7  567       500    2004.4
8  567       500    2004.4
9  567       500    2004.4
```

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
df3[last1] = df3.groupby(['Nos']).apply(lambda x: x[last2] + x[last1]/len(x) ).values
```

instead of

```
count = df3.groupby(['Nos'])[last1].transform('count')
df3[last1] = df3[last2] + df3[last1]/count
```

However, it is slower since the `groupby/apply` is doing an addition and division once for each group, whereas

```
df3[last1] = df3[last2] + df3[last1]/count
```

is performing the addition and division on whole columns. If there are a lot of groups the difference in performance can be significant:

```
In [52]: df3 = pd.concat([df3]*1000)
In [56]: df3['Nos'] = np.random.randint(1000, size=len(df3))

In [57]: %timeit using_transform(df3)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.49 ms per loop

In [58]: %timeit using_apply(df3)
1 loops, best of 3: 270 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wow.. You should be the best teacher to explain in more simple terms.. Thank you !

Comment: The above program does not find this `00:00:00`  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_lac_site.py", line 11, in <module>
    count = df3.groupby(['Ids'])[last1].transform('count')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3159, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Column not found: %s" % key)
KeyError: 'Column not found: 00:00:00'`

Comment: There must be some difference in your real `file_1.csv` and `file_2.csv` compared to the ones posted in the question which is causing the code to fail on your real data.

Comment: I am using the same data that is shown in the question.

Comment: What does `df3.columns` and `last1` return?

Comment: I guess the Question here is about distributing the `last` column value of `file1` to the new last column of `file2` by dividing it by `counts` of respective `Nos` occurrences and `add` that values to the respective values of `00:00:00` column only. But the Program above does the artihmatic operations with previous `(last2)` Column.